# ¿Cómo eliminar archivos duplicados en linux con un script?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

¿Es posible eliminar archivos duplicados con un script en la terminal?

Tengo varios archivos pdf que están duplicados en varios directorios del home; había pensando en hacer un script con `find` para buscarlos, con `diff` para compararlos y así eliminar el duplicado. No obstante soy novato con esto de la terminal y no consigo la forma de integrar esto

No sé si utilizar un bucle para esto, o como lo haría. No coloco ningún codigo de ejemplo porque de verdad no tengo idea de por dónde comenzar.

ilustro un poco mejor con esto:

supóngase que tengo estos pdf en las siguientes carpetas:

```
$ ls home/Descargas/
estadistica.pdf 
matematicas.pdf
examen_2.pdf
```

y tengo tambien el primero y el último pdf en esta carpeta, duplicados:

```
$ ls home/Documentos/
estadistica.pdf
examen_2.pdf
notas.pdf
```

¿Cómo haría para eliminar el duplicado y no borrar todo los pdf? 
intenté con el siguiente comando en una carpeta y la limpie por completo:

```
find -name "*.pdf" -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: En el presente ejemplo los duplicados son los archivos: “estadistica.pdf, examen_2.pdf”,  debido que tiene el mismo nombre (pero en distintas rutas), mi consulta Es que tu condición de saber si son duplicados es a partir del nombre del archivo... o también te basas en el contenido del archivo.

Comment: En ambos casos, tanto por el nombre, como por el contenido, ya que hay algunos archivos que tienen el mismo contenido pero difieren en algunos caracteres en el  nombre. No obstante la mayoría son iguales tanto por nombre, como por el contenido

Comment: Por otro lado también tengo otra duda, como parámetro de tu script le envías una lista de los nombres de los posibles archivos duplicados (en el presente ejemplo sería: “estadista.pdf, examen_2.pdf”) o lo que quieres hacer con tu script es navegar por las rutas que tú indiques para determinar las rutas absolutas de los archivos duplicado y luego eliminarlo..

Comment: Y mi tercera pregunta, es que criterio tienes tú para decidir que archivo permanece y cuáles eliminas, por ejemplo: “Eliminar todos los archivos duplicados de “home/descargas” y  NO ELIMINAR los archivos de la carpeta “home/documentos” “

Comment: No habría forma de enviar una lista con los archivos duplicados, son muchos, más de 800, todos ellos de pdf. Gracias por la aclaración, se me olvidó poner esto en la pregunta. Pienso determinar si un archivo es duplicado o no mediante el comando diff. Leí que arroja un número entre 0, 1 y 2 según lo que encuentre, es decir, si logro capturar lo que diff arroje con #? podría determinar cuales son duplicados y cuales no, creo que implicaría comparar cada archivo contra todos.

Comment: El criterio que utilizaría, sería el primer duplicado que encuentre, es decir: si comparando con diff examen_2.pdf examen_2.pdf borrara cualquiera de los dos, pero solo uno, después me ocuparía de ordenar los resultados.

Comment: Una aclaración respecto a la primera duda, es muy dificil realizarlo en script y puede tener muchos errores a la hora de comparar el contenido (Observación: Puede funcionar para archivos planos, tales .txt), además el tiempo de ejecución y el consumo de procesamiento puede ser alto... Por lo tanto recomiendo realizarlo con solo por el nombre.... (Aunque puede llegar a tener problemas, tal como comentaste; Existe archivos con el mismo nombre pero diferentes contenidos...)

Comment: Ahora con respecto a la segunda y tercera aclaración.... Una solución posible es preguntarte... ¿Por qué se duplica archivos en otras rutas....?,  y empezar  a atacar el problema desde allí (Puede ser que sea una solución mucho más facil, que realizar el script respectivo).

Comment: Se duplicaron tantos archivos por causa de un backup fallido, le estaba haciendo un respaldo al home y resulta que descomprimí los archivos y no tomé en cuenta que pudieran combinarse con otros en diferentes carpetas, haciendo que algunos quedaran duplicados en rutas diferentes.  Así que tenía pensado eliminarlos como había expresado antes; no obstante cualquier solución que me lleve a eliminar los duplicados es aceptable.

Comment: ¿En qué directorios están duplicados? ¿Cuál es el directorio de referencia y cuántos hay que sean la copia? ¿Siempre que se repite un nombre del directorio original se consideran duplicados?

Comment: Los duplicados están a partir del home/ están en Descargas/, Documentos/, Escritorio/ y en algunos directorios que pertenecen a estos. En total hay más de ocho directorios con duplicados. con respecto a la segunda pregunta, no tengo modo de tomar un directorio tal como referencia; y directorios como copia no hay ninguno, previamente eliminé los directorios duplicados y pasé los archivos a otros directorios que con el tiempo guardé también otros pdf únicos, mezclando duplicado con unicos. En la tercera pregunta, en la gran mayoría de la veces se repite el duplicado por nombre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, te recomiendo no hacerlo con un script, sino con un programa hecho por ello. Una opción buena es el [`fslint`](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/):

> fslint  is  a  toolset  to find various problems with filesystems,
>   including duplicate files and problematic filenames
>          etc.
>
> Individual command line tools are available in addition to the GUI and to access them, one can change to,  or  add  to
>          $PATH  the  /usr/share/fslint/fslint directory on a standard install.  Each of these commands in that directory have a
>          --help option which further details its parameters.
>
> ```
>    findup - find DUPlicate files
> ```

Osea, `fslint` es una herramienta que entre otras cosas, encuentre ficheros duplicados. En sistemas basados en Debian (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint etc) lo puedes instalar con

```
sudo apt install fslint
```

---

Si no puedes o no quieres instalar nada, puedes hacer un script simple que compara los md5sums de los ficheros pdf:

```
find / -type f -name '*pdf' -exec md5sum {} \; > md5sums
gawk '{print $1}' md5sums | sort | uniq -d > dupes
while read d; do echo "---"; grep $d md5sums | cut -d ' ' -f 2-; done < dupes
```

Esto de dará una salida como este (en este ejemplo los nombres de los ficheros duplicados son los mismos, pero funciona igual con nombres diferentes):

```
$ while read d; do echo "---"; grep $d md5sums | cut -d ' ' -f 2-; done < dupes 
---
 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include/linux/if_bonding.h
 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/if_bonding.h
---
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include/linux/route.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/route.h
---
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include/drm/Kbuild
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/drm/Kbuild
---
```

Ahora, para eliminar los duplicados y guardar solo uno, puedes hacer algo como:

```
while read d; do 
    echo "---"; grep $d md5sums | cut -d ' ' -f 2-; 
done < dupes | sed 's/^ //' |
awk '{if(/---/){a=0; next} if(a==0){printf "rm \"%s\"\n", $0} a++}'
```

Esto te va a imprimir una lista de comandos `rm` que borraran todos los duplicados menos el primero. Si te parece bien, puedes volver a ejecutarlo y pasarlo por `sh` para que se ejecuten:

```
while read d; do 
    echo "---"; grep $d md5sums | cut -d ' ' -f 2-; 
done < dupes | sed 's/^ //' |
awk '{if(/---/){a=0; next} if(a==0){printf "rm \"%s\"\n", $0} a++}' |
sh
```

Pero cuidado:

- **¡Esto no funcionará correctamente si tus ficheros puedan tener `\n` en su nombre!**
- Esto guardará cualquier fichero se encuentra primero.

¡En serio, `fslint` es mucho mejor!

Comment: Antes de que nadie me acusa de plagio, si este respuesta fue 100% copiada de [aquí](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71201/22222), pero ella es mia también!

Comment: @orcaval seguro que lo copiaste tal como esta? El error me hace pensar que no. Si sigues con problemas, dame un toque en [el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) (escribe `@terdon`) mañana y lo miraremos. Ya es muy tarde aquí y no lo puedo mirar ahora.

Comment: Listo, ya solucioné el problema de los archivos duplicados, con la segunda opción, la del script. Logré descargar el programa `fslint`, pero en el caso de no tener permiso para operar sobre archivos ajenos, del root, que están en mi home, no trabaja; esos archivos los logré eliminar con el script, accedí como root, copié y pegué el script y todo funcionó bien. Muchas gracias. logré liberar 4 Gb de espacio en el disco.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de `rm` no lo puedes usar [directo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5874/137852). Tienes que usar xargs. Depende de la plataforma que estés usando pero podrías hacer algo así:

```
ls -ltr Documentos | awk '{print $9}' | xargs echo rm
```

Si ves que la lista que arroja echo es correcta, entonces remueves el echo y eliminas el archivo con rm.

Personalmente recomiendo que uses pipes y lo imprimas, porque me ha tocado que borro archivos sin querer.

Comment: uy parsear `ls` es bastante sensible. ¿Y si un nombre de fichero tiene espacios?